# Assert.AreEqual and Assert.IsTrue give off two different results

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nunit

I have a function that returns a byte, `GetByte()`. I then have a unit test for this (using NUnit in Unity)

```cs
public void GetByteTest()
{
    var expected = 0b0;

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, GetByte()); // fails
    Assert.IsTrue(expected == GetByte()); // passes
}
```

Very confused about this, especially since the output says:

```
Expected: 0
But was:  0
```

I've also tried `Assert.AreSame()` but with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code. `Assert.AreEqual((int)1, byte(1))` is shorter than code in the post.

Comment: What does `GetNoteBinary` return?

Comment: While you are figuring out what `GetNoteBinary` function is and how it relates to `GetByte` mentioned in the post... please also [edit] to clarify what part of the fine manual on [Assert.AreEqual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.areequal?view=mstest-net-1.3.2) is confusing to you - "Tests whether the specified objects are equal and throws an exception if the two objects are not equal. Different numeric types are treated as unequal even if the logical values are equal. 42L is not equal to 42."

Comment: @Flydog57 `GetNoteBinary` is a typo -- will update that now

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov sorry about that haha, `GetNoteBinary` was left in there when copying my code over. it's been updated. i realized that as i declared the variable `expected` as `var`, it was assuming it was an `int` and the test failed because it was being compared to an int.

Comment: Does `var expected = 0b0;` compile? What type is that? I would expect something like `var expected = 0xb0;`

Comment: @RufusL it compiles, and expected is of type `int`. `expected` either needs to be cast or declared as `byte` (or whatever time you're testing against)

Comment: but `0b0` is not a c# `byte`...maybe it's a unity thing?

Comment: @RufusL no, but it can be implicitly cast as a byte, hence the misunderstanding. i expected `GetByte()` to return `(byte)0b0`. could definitely be a unity thing-- unity is always throwing me curveballs with c# lol

Comment: But `0b0` isn't a byte, it's an int, it's just a different notation for the same value as `0` or `0x0` (but not `0L`)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The documentation you are pointing to is not NUnit, it's MSTest. The quoted statement would not be true for NUnit, which does widening conversions of numerics automatically.

Comment: @Charlie code on other hand clearly uses MSTest once since as you've pointed out https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/assertions/classic-assertions/Assert.AreEqual.html will not fail that assertion... So we both call OP for not precisely specifying what they have... and both of our comments should be flagged as rude... (FluentAssertions for the win :) )

Comment: Also based on the answer provided by OP the type they have for "actual" not even numeric... so really all that talk about whether particular `AreEqual` happen to use widening conversions or not is not really applicable... (the code in the question no longer shows that - original version was *hinting* at such possibility).

Answer (score 2):

While `expected == GetNoteBinary()` is true, since `expected` is declared with `var`, it requires a cast to `byte` to be compared with another byte; `Assert.AreEqual` is trying to compare it as `int`.

```
Assert.AreEqual((NoteBinary)expected, GetNoteBinary()); // passes
```

The lesson here is that `Assert.AreEqual` can compare *different types* and you must be very careful about which types you're comparing; never leave it ambiguous.

Comment: Odd this worked just fine for me...

byte x = 0b0;
int y = 0b0;
Assert.AreEqual(x, y); // passes
Assert.IsTrue(x == y); // passes

Comment: @ZachHutchins huh, that's super weird. i have no idea why it doesn't do that for me. are you using unity? maybe it's the version of NUnit that unity uses.

Comment: I am using version 3.12.0

Comment: @ZachHutchins interestingly I just tested `byte x = 0b0; int y = 0; Assert.AreEqual(x, y); Assert.AreEqual(y, x); Assert.IsTrue(x == y); Debug.Log($"{x.Equals(y)} - {y.Equals(x)} - {x == y} - {y == x}");` all three `Assert`s pass but it logs `False - True - True - True` .. so the question is how does `Assert.AreEqual` check for equality internally ?

Comment: @derHugo I could tell you how NUnit's `Assert.AreEqual` works internally but (a) it won't fit in a comment and (b) we don't know if NUnit's is really being used by the poster.

Comment: @Charlie due to the tags it is probably the built-in [`UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Assertions.Assert.html) .. possible of course that they internally are using NUnit though .. though OP is a bit unclear on that .. might as well be directly using "NUnit in Unity" ^^